# Tags create/edit/delete hooks in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hook

I need hooks if tags have removed, created and edited. I have not found them in the WordPress Codex / [Function Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/).

For categories:

```php
edit_category
create_category
delete_category
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explicitly target tags, you'll need `create_$taxonomy`, `edit_$taxonomy` and `delete_$taxonomy` where `$taxonomy` is `post_tag` (ie `create_post_tag`, `edit_post_tag` and `delete_post_tag`).  They're mentioned in passing in (eg) the [`wp_insert_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/).

Tags are a taxonomy, so the generic actions `create_term`, `edit_term`, and `delete_term` would work as well, though they'll also fire for other taxonomies (such as categories).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use dynamic hooks to taxonomies:

```
edit_post_tag

create_post_tag

delete_post_tag
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these action hooks that you can find in the [Wordpress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org):

To know taxonomy **Action Hooks** and **Filter Hooks**, can go to [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=_%7B%24taxonomy%7D)

For this case, you can use different Action Hooks:

- [**created_{$taxonomy}**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_taxonomy/)

Fired after cache has been cleaned. To execute before cache has been cleaned use [create_{$taxonomy}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/create_taxonomy/) action hook

```
add_action( "created_*your_taxonomy*", "fired_on_created_term_of_taxonomy", 10, 3 );
function fired_on_created_term_of_taxonomy( $term_id, $taxonomy_id, $args ){...}
```

- [**edit_{$taxonomy}**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_taxonomy/)

This hook is fired before term cache has been cleaned. (For example: if in your function execute `get_term($term_id)` you're going to have old term, not the updated term data)

```
add_action( "edit_example_taxonomy", "fired_on_edit_term_of_taxonomy", 10, 3 );
function fired_on_edit_term_of_taxonomy( $term_id, $taxonomy_id, $args ){...}
```

- [**edited_{$taxonomy}**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edited_taxonomy/)

This hook is very similar to hook before, but for example, you execute `get_term($term_id)` in the fired function, you're going to have the updated term

```
add_action( "edited_example_taxonomy", "fired_on_edited_term_of_taxonomy", 10, 3 );
function fired_on_edited_term_of_taxonomy( $term_id, $taxonomy_id, $args ){...}
```

- [**delete_{$taxonomy}**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_taxonomy/)

Fired on delete term of taxonomy

```
add_action( "delete_example_taxonomy", "fired_on_delete_term_of_taxonomy", 10, 4 );
function fired_on_delete_term_of_taxonomy( $term_id, $taxonomy_id, $deleted_term, $object_ids ){...}
```