# WordPress Edit/Create Tag Hooks Not Firing

Tags: wordpress

I've been trying to figure out how to add custom fields to WordPress tags & categories. I've been following this [guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/extending-wordpress-taxonomies/) and I've manage to make the categories work, and also understand what's going on. I'm trying to use the same reasoning however, but it seems I can't do the same thing when it comes to tags. All I need is to add 1 extra text field to both the Tag Create Fields, as well as the Tag Edit Fields. I believe the issue is happening with the

`create_post_tag`
and
`edit_post_tag`

The code looks as follows:

```
// Tags Create
function add_extra_fields_to_tag($taxonomy_name){
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="tag-custom-title">Tag Custom Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="tag-custom-title" id="tag-custom-title"/>
        <p>This is the text that will be used as the page's H1.</p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action('add_tag_form_fields','add_extra_fields_to_tag');

function save_extra_taxonomy_fields_tag($term_id){

    //collect all term related data for this new taxonomy
    $term_item = get_term($term_id,'tag');
    $term_slug = $term_item->slug;

    //collect our custom fields
    $term_tag_custom_title = sanitize_text_field($_POST['tag-custom-title']);
 
    //save our custom fields as wp-options
    update_option('term_tag_custom_title_' . $term_slug, $term_tag_custom_title); 
}
add_action('create_post_tag','save_extra_taxonomy_fields_tag');

// Tags Edit
function edit_extra_fields_for_tag($term){

    //collect the term slug
    $term_slug = $term->slug;

    //collect our saved term field information
    $term_tag_custom_title = get_option('term_tag_custom_title_' . $term_slug); 

    //output our additional fields?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row">
            <label for="tag-text"> Tag Custom Title </label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="tag-custom-title" id="tag-custom-title" value="<?php echo $term_tag_custom_title; ?>"/>
            <p class="description">This is the text that will be used as the page's H1.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
}
add_action('edit_tag_form_fields','edit_extra_fields_for_tag');
add_action('edit_post_tag','save_extra_taxonomy_fields_tag');
```

Wouldn't the $TAXONOMY_NAME for tags be `post_tag`? After reading [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952248/tags-create-edit-delete-hooks-in-wordpress) I also tried `term`.

I've been trying multiple solutions but nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using WP > 2.3.0 version. Then to check if the hook actually trigger, try:

```
    function save_extra_taxonomy_fields_tag($term_id){
        //Debug
        var_dump($term_id);
        die();

        //collect all term related data for this new taxonomy
        $term_item = get_term($term_id,'tag');
        $term_slug = $term_item->slug;
    
        //collect our custom fields
        $term_tag_custom_title = sanitize_text_field($_POST['tag-custom-title']);
     
        //save our custom fields as wp-options
        update_option('term_tag_custom_title_' . $term_slug, $term_tag_custom_title); 
    }
    add_action('edit_post_tag','save_extra_taxonomy_fields_tag');
    add_action('create_post_tag','save_extra_taxonomy_fields_tag');
```

And if it shows the term id, check the further code